# Laravel giving illegal string offsets while trying to loop over a json api response

Tags: php, laravel

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return Application|Factory|View|Response
     * @throws RequestException
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $url = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees";
        $response = Http::get($url);

        if ($response->successful()) {
            return view('welcome', ['dummy' => $response->json()]);
        }
        return $response->throw();
    }
}
```

Simple API request to some dummy api data

Route

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

View

```
@foreach($dummy as $item)
        {{$item['employee_name']}}
@endforeach
```

Error occurs in the foreach `Illegal string offset 'employee_name'`

changing the foreach to use `{{$item->employee_name}}` gives the `Trying to get property 'employee_name' of non-object` error

printing the $response object gives me an array of data from the dummy api so one should think being able to loop over it like an array should work ?

`http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees` dummy api if you need it

Running the latest laravel version

Comment: Right before your return view but inside your if check, add `Log::info($response->json());` to your controller, and then look at what is in your log file to see what `$dummy` will contain. It sounds like it may be a single dimension array.

Comment: Dumping the data inside of laravels debugbar gave me an answer, apparantly the array consisted of a status and then another array called data with all of the items, using DigitalDrifters answer fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't accessing the data index which has the actual array of items you're trying to loop:

```
@foreach($dummy['data'] as $item)
    {{$item['employee_name']}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yep, that was it seems the array had a success object as well as a data array with all the items